# In a Bayesian network, is $P(J|B)$ the same as $P(B|J)$?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem, bayesian-network

In a network like this:

[image]

Is $P(J|B)$ the same as $P(B|J)$?

Since $P(J|B)=\sum _{a,e}P(B,J,A=a,E=e)= \alpha P(B)\sum _{a,e}P(J|A)P(A|B,E)P(E) = P(B|J)$

Because $P(B|J)=\sum _{a,e}P(B,J,A=a,E=e)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily, because $$P(J|B)=\frac{P(J,B)}{P(B)}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{P(B)}}\sum\limits_{a,e} P(B,J,A=a,E=e)$$
and
$$P(B|J)=\frac{P(J,B)}{P(J)}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{P(J)}}\sum\limits_{a,e} P(B,J,A=a,E=e)$$

Comment: But if I calculate the distribution of those, i.e $<P(J|B),P(\lnot J|B)> $ and $<P(B|J),P(\lnot B|J)> $ in both cases the $\alpha$ hide those denominators, so will they be different?

Comment: In fact, $\alpha$ is $\frac{1}{denominator}$ and it's different for both cases, unless $P(J)=P(B)$. With the most of Bayesian inference algorithms, $\alpha$ hides these details indeed. However, algorithms like  Kalman and Particle Filters include normalisation phase, which basically means enforcing $\alpha$ back.